# md-autocomplete hides fixed nav-bar with autosuggestion

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwaraa), Where I have created a nav-bar, which is fixed on top. When I scroll down and search something, navbar disappears when it shows auto-complete results.

Here is HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="autocompletedemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-z1 header_navbar" layout="column"
                style="background-color:#027cd8; min-height:100px; padding-left:1%; padding-right:1.25%; box-shadow:none; position: fixed  !important">
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
      <p>Use <code>md-autocomplete</code> to search for matches from local or remote data sources.</p>
      <md-autocomplete ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="0" placeholder="What is your favorite US state?">
        <md-item-template>
          <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
          No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
          <a ng-click="ctrl.newState(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
        </md-not-found>
      </md-autocomplete>
    </form>
  </md-content>
    </md-toolbar>
  <div style="background-color:#027cd8; height:500px"></div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('MyApp')
      .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

  function DemoCtrl ($timeout, $q, $log) {
    var self = this;

    self.simulateQuery = false;
    self.isDisabled    = false;

    // list of `state` value/display objects
    self.states        = loadAll();
    self.querySearch   = querySearch;
    self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
    self.searchTextChange   = searchTextChange;

    self.newState = newState;

    function newState(state) {
      alert("Sorry! You'll need to create a Constituion for " + state + " first!");
    }

    // ******************************
    // Internal methods
    // ******************************

    /**
     * Search for states... use $timeout to simulate
     * remote dataservice call.
     */
    function querySearch (query) {
      var results = query ? self.states.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.states,
          deferred;
      if (self.simulateQuery) {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve( results ); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
      } else {
        return results;
      }
    }

    function searchTextChange(text) {
      $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
    }

    function selectedItemChange(item) {
      $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
    }

    /**
     * Build `states` list of key/value pairs
     */
    function loadAll() {
      var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
              Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
              Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
              Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
              North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
              South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
              Wisconsin, Wyoming';

      return allStates.split(/, +/g).map( function (state) {
        return {
          value: state.toLowerCase(),
          display: state
        };
      });
    }

    /**
     * Create filter function for a query string
     */
    function createFilterFor(query) {
      var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

      return function filterFn(state) {
        return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
      };

    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: This is happening due to fixed position of md-toolbar.

Comment: @RahulPratapSingh But there should be some way to fix it also, which I couldn't find.

Comment: Why are you using fixed positioning? Tell me so that I can help out.

Comment: @RahulPratapSingh Because I want to keep the navbar visible always on top of screen, even if user scrolls down.